# How can be attached starwars data to R studio?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have downloaded running install.packages("tidyverse") to Rstudio. The final output parade show below link:

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp67y8VU\downloaded_pakages
Though when  I checked by writing library(tidyverse) in console below message come:

Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

how can i fix this problem in Rstudio?

I have type view(starwars) data but come below message:

Error in View : object 'starwars' not found

Comment: Your first error message indicates that you haven't successfully installed `tidyverse`.  Based on the information you've provided, we can't say why.  Once `tidyverse` has been installed, `library(tidyverse) will make the `starwars` tibble available to you.

Comment: Thanks Limey and Greeting from KBL!
 I have several times installed tidyverse . below output come:
 The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8WsaS0\downloaded_packages’

After running: library (Tidyverse) response as below:
Error in library(tidyverse) : 
  there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

I have also tried to installed through package achieve file (zip.tar.gz) . Then I received this output:
Installation of package ‘C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/downloaded_packages/tidyverse_2.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: "I have several times installed tidyverse": not true.  The fact that `library(tidyverse)` results in `Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’` demonstrates this.  This fact is proven by `C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/downloaded_packages/tidyverse_2.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit` which is R-speak for "There was a problem with the installation and it failed".  We cannot tell you why bsed on the information you have so far provided.  I suggest you search on the "non zero exit status" message or "tidyverse failed to install".

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` hasn't been installed, so you need to install it.

Run `install.packages("tidyverse")`, then try `library(tidyverse)` again, and it should work.